# Multiple testing/multiple regression models- adjustment necessary or not?

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons

I have a question about the issue of level adjustment.
Suppose we have a sample which can be divided into sub-samples corresponding to risk factors, that is RF1 yes/RF1 no; RF2 yes/RF2 no; RF3 yes/RF4 no.
Now I'm interested in some endpoint, for example the blood pressure. I want to investigate whether this endpoint is different when having the risk factor or not and I want to do this analysis for each of them; hence I have three t-tests.
From my understanding, I now have to correct, e.g. using Bonferroni or any other procedure, right?

But I don't get it completely. Another situation: I have a sample which can be divided into two subsets S1 and S2 and I want to test for differences between S1 and S2 concerning 3 different endpoints, e.g. age, weight and blood pressure. So now I have again 3 tests, but it seems to me that I don't necessarily have to do an adjustment, right?

Last question: Suppose have 3 subsets and I want to fit regression models for each of the three subsets (dependent and independent variables are the same for all three models but I fit a separate model on each subset). Do I have to adjust the p-values on significance of the coefficients? I would say yes. However, I have the impression that this is never done.

So, a lot of questions, I'm looking forward to your replies :-)

Comment: If the composite null is equally likely in all three cases, then there is essentially no difference between the three cases. You will have slight differences as regards correlation structures and their effects on multiplicity adjustments, but that is minor in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Some thoughts on the issue: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503532/should-i-correct-for-multiple-comparisons-if-i-generate-hypothesis/503538#503538 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468620/correction-for-multiple-testing-in-multiple-regression-analysis/468622#468622

Comment: @BigBendRegion: I think I don't get it, you mean it's not much difference whether or not I do an adjustment?

Comment: @Lewian: thanks, this is what I somehow supposed to read, that there is no clear rule on that...

Comment: No, I mean the issue of whether to adjust is the same in the three cases.  Multiplicity adjustment becomes more important when the the composite null is more likely. Case in point: ESP studies.  The data structure is hardly relevant to the the issue of whether to adjust.

Comment: @Kathrin: Understanding the implications of any decision, and then deciding responsibly based on this understanding will always trump a "rule" in statistics. (Which of course makes it hard, at least but not only for non-statisticians.)