# Do the p-values produced by lmerTest::lmer need to be adjusted for multiple comparisons?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, p-value, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I am running a fairly simple linear mixed model with multiple observations per patient, comparing a lab value to a reference group (healthy control). Here's some fake data:

```
dat <- data.table(Patient_no = sample(1:100, replace = T, 1000),
           Lab_value = sample(35:50, replace = T, 1000))

dat[, Disease := fifelse(Patient_no < 30, "Control", 
              fifelse(Patient_no < 40, "Disease1", 
                      fifelse(Patient_no < 60, "Disease2",
                              fifelse(Patient_no < 80, "Disease3",
                                      fifelse(Patient_no <= 100, "Disease4", NA_character_)))))]
```

If I call summary with the lmerTest package, then I get a list of p-values in the coefficient table. Obviously since I have used sample here, the p-values are far from significant, but these serve only to illustrate my question.

Would I need to adjust these values for multiple hypothesis testing? I see these as independent hypotheses so I am leaning towards no, but I would appreciate some unbiased input here.

```
summary(lmer("Lab_value ~ Disease + (1|Patient_no)", dat))

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: "Lab_value ~ Disease + (1|Patient_no)"
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 5884.6

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.81306 -0.84289  0.01993  0.84415  1.85056 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Patient_no (Intercept)  0.755   0.8689  
 Residual               20.501   4.5278  
Number of obs: 1000, groups:  Patient_no, 100

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      42.1899     0.3109 86.2420 135.687   <2e-16 ***
DiseaseDisease1   0.8155     0.6147 86.6013   1.327    0.188    
DiseaseDisease2   0.6739     0.4869 83.4971   1.384    0.170    
DiseaseDisease3   0.3787     0.4911 87.5473   0.771    0.443    
DiseaseDisease4   0.4471     0.4899 93.6628   0.913    0.364    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) DssDs1 DssDs2 DssDs3
DiseaseDss1 -0.506                     
DiseaseDss2 -0.639  0.323              
DiseaseDss3 -0.633  0.320  0.404       
DiseaseDss4 -0.635  0.321  0.405  0.402
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What hypothesis do you want to test and for what reason? For instance, the advice on how to proceed if you want to report one p-value for a hypothesis of interest will differ from the advice on how to proceed if you want to screen variables for significance and then remove the insignificant ones as a feature selection method (an approach that is fraught with problems).

Comment: Thank you! This is just a single lab value without any other tests. What I am confused about is whether or not testing healthy controls versus disease 1, then healthy versus disease 2, etc. are considered independent hypotheses. So I really just have this one linear mixed model that will stand alone. The rest of this project has independent experiments that try to go deeper into the molecular mechanism alluded to from the analysis above. Based on follow-ups, I am pretty confident in our findings, just less confident about whether or not I need to call to p.adjust :D

Comment: No. You don't need to adjust the p-values reported by the model (ie model-based p-values). You have one model to explain all your data. This is quite different from applying multiple tests to subsets of the data (which creates multiplicity that needs to be adjusted for).

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468620/correction-for-multiple-testing-in-multiple-regression-analysis/468622#468622

Comment: The usefulness of 'corrections' for multiple comparisons varies wildly depending on context and, unfortunately, on who you ask. Given that you are describing a preliminary component of a larger study (from you comment above), you should not apply any 'correction' as false positives will be detected and corrected by the next set of experiments. The loss of power that comes with 'correction' is often more important than the reduction in false positives in preliminary research. Read more here: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286