# Do i need to adjust p values in correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, p-value, multiple-comparisons

I recently computed pairwise correlations with a data set that consists of 1200 participants which all completed 5 questionnaires. So i computed 10 correlations ( each questionnaire with all other questionnaires).
Do I have to adjust the p values of my correlations for multiple tests?

Comment: Only if you feel like it.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Are you testing multiple correlations? // You might be interested in questions tagged with [tag:multiple-comparisons].

Comment: If you want to protect yourself against an unacceptably high rate of false positive results, then definitely yes.  The adjustment is complicated due to the correlations among the results, but a conservative approach acts as if all ten were independent.  Please tell us, then, a little more about *why* you compute these p-values and how you intend to interpret them.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your answer! I computed all p-values to know which correlations are significant and which ones are not. Some of the 5 different questionnaires tend to measure the same latent construct, so i wanted to know how high the correlations of the total scores of each person of the questionnaires are..

Comment: You hint at several different objectives.  "Know how high" doesn't require p-values at all: it asks only for estimates.  "Significant" just pushes the answer back to another level: what does "significant" mean for you?  Finally, are you truly interested in pairwise correlation or is your real objective to understand how all five questionnaires are interrelated?  The latter would suggest some kind of PCA or factor analysis.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468620/correction-for-multiple-testing-in-multiple-regression-analysis/468622#468622

Comment: @whuber i need to know both, since i can't interpret non significant correlations but need to know how high the significant ones are. Significant for me means that the p-value is <.01.

Comment: Also, in this step I do not want to get to know if all questionnaires share a common latent factor, I just want to compute the correlations of the scale scores

Comment: A permutation test would be an attractive approach to this problem.