# A question about Adjusted P-value

Tags: r, p-value, multiple-comparisons

*I have five independent variables and one dependent variable. If I apply the univariate analysis between each independent variable and dependent variable before running the multiple regression, **do I need to adjust the p-values**? In the medical field, we prefer to evaluate the relationship between each explanatory variable and the dependent variable separately before applying multiple regression. Thanks for the advice.**

Comment: What is the goal? Can you give more context & details? Maybe manova ...

Comment: Addressed here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468620/correction-for-multiple-testing-in-multiple-regression-analysis/468622#468622

Comment: @
kjetil b halvorsen, thanks for the reply. We want to evaluate the relashionship between each explanatory variable with dependent variable (suppose: income with three levels) before considering all independent variables together and running the multiple regression.

Comment: P¨lease add this new information as an edit to the post, as comments are ephemeral and are often not seen by many!