# How to correct for multiple testing in linear mixed models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, bonferroni, type-i-and-ii-errors

I want to correct for alpha error accumulation for my 10 crossed linear mixed models. The random parameters are specified as follows: random intercepts for *subject* and *stimulus* and a random slope for *factor1*,*factor2*, ... to *factor10* in *subject* are estimated. The R-Code looks like this.

```r
m1<-lmer(outcome1 ~ factor1 + (factor1|subject) + (1|stimulus), data=dat)
m2<-lmer(outcome2 ~ factor2 + (factor2|subject) + (1|stimulus), data=dat)
# ...
m9<-lmer(outcome9 ~ factor9 + (factor9|subject) + (1|stimulus), data=dat)
m10<-lmer(outcome10 ~ factor10 + (factor10|subject) + (1|stimulus), data=dat)
```

Is a simple Bonferroni-Correction appropriate for this issue?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to CV! Which is the question here? The title and the body are asking about two different things.

Comment: I want to correct for multiple testing (alpha error accumulation) in my linear mixed models. I have 10 seperate models [m1, m2, ..., m10] with 10 different outcomes [outcome1, outcome2, .., outcome10] and 10 different independent variables named [factor1, factor2, .., factor10]. Is Bonferoni Correction - like in several other domains of inference statistics - the right way to go to correct for multiple testing in linear mixed models?

Comment: Although not about mixed effects models, I suggest to read this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468620/correction-for-multiple-testing-in-multiple-regression-analysis/468622#468622

Comment: Thanks, Christian Hennig, great guideline !

Comment: IF you want to correct for multiple comparisons, AND you want to control the family wise error rate (either for tests or intervals), then Bonferroni always works, but is conservative. That means there are more powerful options readily available that achieve these two objectives. They do that by using correlation structures (in mixed models and otherwise), and, in the case of multiple testing, by using stepwise methods.

Comment: Thank you very much, @BigBendRegion! Do you have any ressources to share on this particular topic?

Comment: Resampling-Based Multiple Testing: Examples and Methods for P-Value Adjustment
P Westfall, SS Young
Wiley, 1993
//
Simultaneous inference in general parametric models
T Hothorn, F Bretz, P Westfall
Biometrical Journal: Journal of Mathematical Methods in Biosciences, 2008
//
Multiple comparisons and multiple tests using SAS
PH Westfall, RD Tobias, RD Wolfinger
SAS Institute, 2011