# Do I need to apply the Bonferroni correction test if it's different tests on different dimensions but generated by the same agents?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, bonferroni

I am running an AB test on a customer support tool - I have changed one feature in the support tool. My unit of randomisation is the agent solving tickets, and my unit of measurement is tickets solved. The metric to be tested is ticket resolution rate.

It basically looks like the following:

- Control Group: X agents, each will solve N tickets
- Treatment Group: Y agents, each will solve N tickets.

Now, there are five categories of tickets depending on their topic, so I'm running a t-test with 5% alpha on each category.

Tests to run:

- Category A tickets, t-test, 5% alpha
- Category B tickets, t-test, 5% alpha
- etc.

My question here is: do I need to apply a Bonferroni correction? Or can I just use the regular 5% alpha for each test? The datasets of tickets are different for the different categories, but they are completed by the same agents.

Comment: What I wrote [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468620/correction-for-multiple-testing-in-multiple-regression-analysis/468622#468622) applies. There is no fixed rule, and it will depend on what error rate you want to control.