The problem of double adjustment of p-values in multilevel models with categorical predictors
I have a set of around 30 multilevel models which have the same predictor variables (and the same cluster variable), but different outcome variables. Since there are so many models, I want to perform some overall adjustment of the p-values.
Some of the predictors in the model are categorical with more than 2 levels, and some are continuous. For the categorical predictors, I want an omnibus test which tests all levels of the variable jointly, instead of the tests for separate variable levels. This is obtainable e.g. in R using the joint_tests function in the emmeans package.
However, during this "concatenation" of the tests, it is already possible to perform some p-value adjustments for multiple testing.
I am wondering how this is related to the "overall" p-value adjustment which I mentioned earlier. Should both adjustments be performed, or just one?
If both adjustments are performed, are the overall adjustments applied to the original p-values of separate variable levels, or are they applied to the omnibus p-values after the "concatenation"?

Generally adjustments are not mandatory and depend on what exactly you want to achieve. If you adjust a lot, you will control the type I error probability over a larger set of hypotheses but it'll cost you power. For general discussion see my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468620/correction-for-multiple-testing-in-multiple-regression-analysis/468622#468622

Thanks, but this is too broad and general. I am wondering specifically about the double correction on the p-values of the joint tests of categorical variable levels.

You do not need to do any adjustments that related to the numbers of levels of factors, because joint tests already implicitly have a kind of Scheffe-style adjustment, which is fairly conservative. So the only question is whether you want to adjust for the fact that you have so many models; and it sounds like you do. It seems to me the appropriate thing to do would be a Bonferroni adjustment for 30 tests. Or equivalently, multiply all the P values by 30 and truncate the results at 1.
