Multiple Test Correction in RT-qPCR Studies with Small Gene Set
I conducted an experiment using RT-qPCR to analyze the expression of a small, manually selected set of 12 genes. These genes were chosen based on their close biological relationship and their involvement in a specific process under study. Unlike RNA-seq, which screens thousands of genes simultaneously, this study is more focused and hypothesis-driven, targeting a small number of genes of known relevance.
One recurring question is how to handle multiple test correction in this context. While corrections are mandatory in high-throughput experiments, applying them to small, interrelated and probably dependent genes
Key Considerations

Biological Dependence:

Since the genes were manually selected due to their biological relevance, one could argue that strict multiple test correction might be overly conservative and lead to false negatives.


Low Dimensional Data:

In this case, the impact of multiple test correction is less severe, with a confidence level of 0,95 I don't even reach the probability of one single false positve (12 genes x 0,05). Some researchers suggest it might not even be necessary if the study is hypothesis-driven.


Independence (lack) of Genes:

The selected genes are not independent; they are part of the same biological network, and probably we will find collinearity among them. This violates a key assumption of most correction methods, which treat tests as independent.  Is there alternative approaches? (just for curiosity)




How necessary do you think multiple test correction is for this experiment?
How do you balance proven biological dependence among the studied biomarkers in targeted studies like these? Is there any reasoning behind the dependence about multiple hypothesis?

Thanks in advance for the contribution.

Maybe this helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468620/correction-for-multiple-testing-in-multiple-regression-analysis/468622#468622 In may view the major issue is not so much whether "it is necessary", but rather that you interpret results appropriately taking the issue into account (which in principle is also possible if you don't use a formal correction method, but many people are tempted to overinterpret then).

Independence is something very special, and dependence is the rule with real data. Not assuming independence will always play things safer. Note however that several correction methods are often presented as if they assumed independence, even if they in fact don't.

What I understood it ok, here it is posed as the genes as independent variables. In my case, my genes are the response variable. The model is exactly the same for the 12 genes, because I hypothesized that are influenced the same way for the same covariates (weight, sex..). I'm not sure if we're talking the same

Which correction method that you may want to use assumes independence? By the way the term "independent variable" is often used inconsistently with stochastic independence and independence of tests.

Ok. I guess no one, but Bonferroni may be too conservative in dependent variables.  Still, the hypothesis of correcting works differently if significance comes from a multivariate model? Which I don't get if is meant to predictors or response variable. I maybe confusing terms about stochastic indepndence or independence of tests
