Post-hoc Bonferroni correction in rm-ANOVA: how many times to adjust for conventionally
I was under the impression that post-hoc Bonferroni correction after ANOVA would entail adjusting for all statistical comparisons made within a study (e.g, 2 pair-wise comparisons * 10 variables = 20).
However, increasingly I’ve noticed papers where post-hoc Bonferroni is only applied for the number of tests done for a single variable.
An example would be Table 2 of this paper. According to the footnote, the adjusted p value cut-off is 0.0125 despite the fact that so many variables were tested.
Would be very grateful if someone could shed some light on this, thank you very much

Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468620/correction-for-multiple-testing-in-multiple-regression-analysis/468622#468622

Multiplicity correction is a somewhat divisive topic -- it really depends on whether you want to make statistical "claims" or generate further hypotheses. Almost no-one is going to recommend a Bonferroni correction, there's better approaches if you want to correct. Still, it's true that they only addressed multiple comparisons within each parameter (3 timepoints + the omnibus test), so the fact that they tested many leaves a lot of multiplicity on the table. I would take much stronger issue with the within-group comparison versus baseline & lack of control however.

The title of the paper says "pilot study". So the hope is there will be follow-up studies to confirm the results. So being "liberal" with multiple comparison correction is understandable. Also, the observed p-values before any MCC are presented as $p<.001$. So while they use a MCC for 4, they seem to have margin for 50 comparisons. Given this, I do not see a major problem here.

This debate isn't new at all. Way back when I was just starting grad school, about 35 years ago, there was discussion over whether to adjust at all, and, if so, for how many comparisons and which ones. All in one paper? All in one table? All that you had ever done in your life? All that came from one regression?
There is no one right answer; you can do whichever you want as long as you a) State what you did and b) Can justify it, at least to yourself (but possibly to a reviewer who asks why you did what you did).
When deciding Remember that if you cut the risk of type 1 error, you increase the risk of type 2. That may be worse, depending on the situation. The usual starting points of sig. level of 0.05 and power of 0.8 are arbitrary. Suppose you come up with a new treatment for an incurable and usually fatal illness. Then a type 1 error means you give a useless treatment to people who are dying anyway, while a type 2 error means you deny people a treatment that could save their lives.
